# SQL a shortcut for a condition?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, conditional-statements

in SQL i am trying to check for the following condition

```
WHERE (col1 is null and col2 is not null) or (col1 is not null and col2 is null)
```

is there a logical way to make this condition shorter?

Description of what i am trying to do

I have 2 tables each table have 3 columns

```
Table1(Ft)  Table2(Dt)
ID          ID
F1          D1
F2          D2
F3          D3
```

the F columns are of integer type D columns are of Datetime type

```
F1 correspondes to D1
F2 correspondes to D2
F3 correspondes to D3
```

i want to select rows where F is empty and D is filled or D is empty and F is filled
Here is the full code, make it shorter!

```
SELECT f1, 
       f2, 
       f3, 
       d1, 
       d2, 
       d3 
FROM   ftable Ft 
       INNER JOIN dtable Dt 
               ON Ft.ID= Dt.ID 
WHERE  ( ( ( d1 IS NULL 
             AND f1 IS NOT NULL ) 
            OR ( d1 IS NOT NULL 
                 AND f1 IS NULL ) ) 
          OR ( ( d2 IS NULL 
                 AND f2 IS NOT NULL ) 
                OR ( d2 IS NOT NULL 
                     AND f2 IS NULL ) ) 
          OR ( ( d2 IS NULL 
                 AND f2 IS NOT NULL ) 
                OR ( d3 IS NOT NULL 
                     AND f3 IS NULL ) ) )
```

Comment: I'm not aware of any way to shorten it - and there's no real cost associated with the length of the predicates. Both of the posted answers (so far) are flawed to one degree or another, and could *obscure* the intention (if they did work). Write clear code that you (or another) can clearly read and understand in 6 months time.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever just did!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try

```
WHERE (ISNULL(col1) != ISNULL(col2))
```

Oh, that was for MySQL. For SQL Server you can try this one:

```
WHERE (NULLIF(col1, col2) IS NOT NULL)
```

Comment: That second condition doesn't preclude both columns being non-NULL.

Answer (score 2):

Since `col1 IS NULL` and `colx IS NOT NULL` are mutually exclusive (cannot be both at the same time) and collectively exhaustive (must be one of them), you can use the XOR operation. I don't know much about SQL Server, but I think it uses the `^` operator:

```
WHERE col1 IS NULL ^ col2 IS NULL
```

This basically says "col1 is null, or col2 is null, but not both".

Reference:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190277.aspx

Comment: That's a bitwise operator, and requires integral types on either side - not the case here

Comment: already looked for an XOR operator , turned out they are used for bits only

Answer (score 1):

If any of the `column` is `not null` then u wanna show the result. So the shorter `query` will be :

```
select * from Table_Name WHERE col1 IS not NULL OR col2 IS not NULL
```

and if the columns are of type bit then :

```
select * from Table_Name WHERE col1 ^ col2
```